# Flutter Firebase Push Notification with button

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to push a notification in a flutter with a button like this in the image and add a separate function to this button. Example Answer or Decline Call.And Sorry for the image quality.

PS: I see there is a similar question other [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809766/is-there-any-way-to-implement-push-notifications-with-action-buttons-in-flutter) but it does not resolve my problem.

[image]

Like this.

[image]

Comment: Hi! This question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/64809766/10595176

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to implement push notifications with action buttons in flutter? Using firebase\_messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809766/is-there-any-way-to-implement-push-notifications-with-action-buttons-in-flutter)