# How to dismiss notification after action button clicked without opening the app?

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, notifications, dismiss

I am showing a notification using [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) and there is action buttons that dismiss the notification, but the problem is if the app is in the background, and the action button clicked, then it dismisses the notification but open the app too which I don't want. So how can I just dismiss the notification when the action button is clicked without opening the app? The notification also contains another action button that opens the app but the second should not.
What should I do in that case?

This is what currently happens:
[image]

Code to show notification:

```
AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
         content: NotificationContent(
           id: 333,
           title: 'Incoming Call',
           body: 'from $callerName',
           category: NotificationCategory.Call,
           channelKey: 'call_channel',
           largeIcon: 'asset://assets/images/logo_square.png',
           wakeUpScreen: true,
           fullScreenIntent: true,
           autoDismissible: false,
           showWhen: true,
           displayOnBackground: true,
           displayOnForeground: true,
           payload: {
             "callerName": callerName,
             "callerUsername": callerUsername,
             "callerID": callerID,
             "callerToken": callerToken,
             "callerImage": callerImage,
           },
         ),
         actionButtons: [
           NotificationActionButton(
               key: 'ACCEPT',
               label: 'Accept Call',
               color: Colors.green,
               autoDismissible: true,
           ),
           NotificationActionButton(
               key: 'REJECT',
               label: 'Reject Call',
               isDangerousOption: true,
               autoDismissible: true,
           ),
         ]
     );
```

Comment: Add code that notification action buttons.

Comment: Code Added, please check!

Comment: Check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809766/is-there-any-way-to-implement-push-notifications-with-action-buttons-in-flutter/68316043#68316043

Comment: Their site (https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) says `Add an option to choose if a notification action should bring the app to foreground or not.` in the "Next Steps" section, so I think that is not supported by that package yet.

Comment: Okay, I found the answer, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer while surfing the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/rafaelsetragni/awesome_notifications) of [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications).
The `notification` can straightly be dismissed without opening the app by adding `buttonType` as `ActionButtonType.DisabledAction` in the `NotificationActionButton`

*just like this:*

```
NotificationActionButton(
   key: 'DISMISS',
   label: 'Dismiss',
   autoDismissible: true,
   buttonType: ActionButtonType.DisabledAction,
   isDangerousOption: true
)
```

**Note: Doing so will not trigger any `receivedAction` in the `actionStream`.**